# android - HorizontalScrollView to list child of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I use this tut http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ for know how to use expanablelistview in android but i have a problem, many childviews of my form take a long text then it auto down to 2nd row. I want only single row, so i add a HorizontalScrollView to list_item.xml like this:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

It work but each child get a scroll,..aww (i know it'll happen but got no idea)
Some solution for this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I dont understand your question to be honest. If you don't want that every child has a scroll simply don't wrap it in a scroll view. The ExpandableListView scrolls by default so you don't have to implemented this behavoir yourself.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/sivailango/ExpandableListView-RecylerChildItems

Answer (score 0):

It is not cleared If u don't want to show scrollbar then try this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```